# Sway Wayland, input keyboard only applies to terminal, not to other browser based apps

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, wayland, input

I have a custom keyboard layout like so

```
    input * xkb_layout custom
```

The layout is found in `/usr/local/xkb/x11/symbols`.... (something like that)

And it works... in terminal, but if I open up brave

```
    bindsym $mod+Ctrl+b exec brave-browser
```

It still uses the default layout, and not my custom one, but if I switch to some other layout and back, it works as expected

```
    alias asdf="swaymsg input type:keyboard xkb_layout custom"
    alias aoeu="swaymsg input type:keyboard xkb_layout us"
```

So `aoeu` then `asdf` and it works as expected, but it doesnt work initially which is annoying, and it periodically resets the keyboard back to `us`

This is from the debug logs

```
 122   │ 00:00:00.317 [DEBUG] [sway/config.c:824] Read line 13: 
 123   │ 00:00:00.317 [DEBUG] [sway/config.c:824] Read line 14: input * xkb_layout real-prog-dvorak
 124   │ 00:00:00.317 [INFO] [sway/commands.c:378] Config command: input * xkb_layout real-prog-dvorak
 125   │ 00:00:00.317 [INFO] [sway/commands.c:398] After replacement: input * xkb_layout real-prog-dvorak
 126   │ 00:00:00.317 [DEBUG] [sway/commands/input.c:54] entering input block: *
 127   │ 00:00:00.317 [DEBUG] [sway/config/input.c:15] new_input_config(*)
 128   │ 00:00:00.317 [DEBUG] [sway/commands.c:429] Subcommand: xkb_layout real-prog-dvorak
 129   │ 00:00:00.317 [DEBUG] [sway/commands/input/xkb_layout.c:18] set-xkb_layout for config: * layout: real-prog-dvorak
 130   │ 00:00:00.317 [DEBUG] [sway/config/input.c:15] new_input_config(temp)
 131   │ 00:00:00.322 [DEBUG] [sway/config/input.c:350] Config stored for input *
 132   │ 00:00:00.325 [DEBUG] [sway/config.c:1055] Translated keysyms using config for device '*'
 133   │ 00:00:00.325 [DEBUG] [sway/config.c:824] Read line 15: 
...

ge2_Keyboard')
 866   │ 00:00:01.058 [DEBUG] [sway/input/seat.c:939] adding device 10730:258:Kinesis_Advantage2_Keyboard to seat seat0
 867   │ 00:00:01.092 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xcursor/wlr_xcursor.c:243] Loaded cursor theme 'default' at size 24 (88 available cursors)
 868   │ 00:00:01.092 [DEBUG] [sway/input/seat.c:718] Applying input config to 10730:258:Kinesis_Advantage2_Keyboard
 869   │ 00:00:01.092 [DEBUG] [wlr] [backend/libinput/events.c:95] Added Kinesis Advantage2 Keyboard [10730:258]
 870   │ 00:00:01.092 [DEBUG] [sway/input/input-manager.c:234] adding device: '10730:258:Kinesis_Advantage2_Keyboard'
 871   │ 00:00:01.092 [DEBUG] [sway/input/libinput.c:198] sway_input_configure_libinput_device('*' on '10730:258:Kinesis_Advantage2_Keyboard')
 872   │ 00:00:01.092 [DEBUG] [sway/input/seat.c:939] adding device 10730:258:Kinesis_Advantage2_Keyboard to seat seat0
 873   │ 00:00:01.097 [DEBUG] [sway/input/keyboard.c:912] Adding keyboard 10730:258:Kinesis_Advantage2_Keyboard to group 0x55b58fff7fb0
 874   │ 00:00:01.098 [DEBUG] [wlr] [backend/libinput/events.c:95] Added Kinesis Advantage2 Keyboard Consumer Control [10730:258]
 875   │ 00:00:01.098 [DEBUG] [sway/input/input-manager.c:234] adding device: '10730:258:Kinesis_Advantage2_Keyboard_Consumer_Control'
 876   │ 00:00:01.098 [DEBUG] [sway/input/libinput.c:198] sway_input_configure_libinput_device('*' on '10730:258:Kinesis_Advantage2_Keyboard_Consumer_Control')
 877   │ 00:00:01.098 [DEBUG] [sway/input/seat.c:939] adding device 10730:258:Kinesis_Advantage2_Keyboard_Consumer_Control to seat seat0
 878   │ 00:00:01.103 [DEBUG] [sway/input/keyboard.c:912] Adding keyboard 10730:258:Kinesis_Advantage2_Keyboard_Consumer_Control to group 0x55b58fff7fb0
 879   │ 00:00:01.105 [DEBUG] [wlr] [backend/libinput/events.c:95] Added Kinesis Advantage2 Keyboard System Control [10730:258]
 880   │ 00:00:01.105 [DEBUG] [sway/input/input-manager.c:234] adding device: '10730:258:Kinesis_Advantage2_Keyboard_System_Control'
 881   │ 00:00:01.105 [DEBUG] [sway/input/libinput.c:198] sway_input_configure_libinput_device('*' on '10730:258:Kinesis_Advantage2_Keyboard_System_Control')
 882   │ 00:00:01.105 [DEBUG] [sway/input/seat.c:939] adding device 10730:258:Kinesis_Advantage2_Keyboard_System_Control to seat seat0
 883   │ 00:00:01.109 [DEBUG] [sway/input/keyboard.c:912] Adding keyboard 10730:258:Kinesis_Advantage2_Keyboard_System_Control to group 0x55b58fff7fb0
 884   │ 00:00:01.111 [DEBUG] [wlr] [backend/libinput/events.c:95] Added C270 HD WEBCAM [1133:2085]
 885   │ 00:00:01.111 [DEBUG] [sway/input/input-manager.c:234] adding device: '1133:2085:C270_HD_WEBCAM'
 886   │ 00:00:01.111 [DEBUG] [sway/input/libinput.c:198] sway_input_configure_libinput_device('*' on '1133:2085:C270_HD_WEBCAM')
 887   │ 00:00:01.111 [DEBUG] [sway/input/seat.c:939] adding device 1133:2085:C270_HD_WEBCAM to seat seat0
 888   │ 00:00:01.116 [DEBUG] [sway/input/keyboard.c:912] Adding keyboard 1133:2085:C270_HD_WEBCAM to group 0x55b58fff7fb0
 889   │ 00:00:01.117 [DEBUG] [wlr] [backend/libinput/events.c:95] Added HP, Inc HyperX QuadCast Consumer Control [1008:1169]
 890   │ 00:00:01.117 [DEBUG] [sway/input/input-manager.c:234] adding device: '1008:1169:HP,_Inc_HyperX_QuadCast_Consumer_Control'
 891   │ 00:00:01.117 [DEBUG] [sway/input/libinput.c:198] sway_input_configure_libinput_device('*' on '1008:1169:HP,_Inc_HyperX_QuadCast_Consumer_Control')
 892   │ 00:00:01.117 [DEBUG] [sway/input/seat.c:939] adding device 1008:1169:HP,_Inc_HyperX_QuadCast_Consumer_Control to seat seat0
 893   │ 00:00:01.122 [DEBUG] [sway/input/keyboard.c:912] Adding keyboard 1008:1169:HP,_Inc_HyperX_QuadCast_Consumer_Control to group 0x55b58fff7fb0
 894   │ 00:00:01.123 [DEBUG] [wlr] [backend/libinput/events.c:95] Added USB Optical Mouse [7119:5]
 895   │ 00:00:01.123 [DEBUG] [sway/input/input-manager.c:234] adding device: '7119:5:USB_Optical_Mouse'
 896   │ 00:00:01.123 [DEBUG] [sway/input/libinput.c:198] sway_input_configure_libinput_device('*' on '7119:5:USB_Optical_Mouse')
 897   │ 00:00:01.123 [DEBUG] [sway/input/seat.c:939] adding device 7119:5:USB_Optical_Mouse to seat seat0
 898   │ 00:00:01.123 [DEBUG] [sway/input/seat.c:718] Applying input config to 7119:5:USB_Optical_Mouse
 899   │ 00:00:01.123 [DEBUG] [wlr] [backend/libinput/backend.c:133] libinput successfully initialized

...

1465   │ 00:00:16.114 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1466   │ 00:00:16.114 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1467   │ 00:00:16.114 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/xwm.c:833] unhandled X11 property 378 (_NET_WM_BYPASS_COMPOSITOR) for window 4194307
1468   │ 00:00:16.114 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1469   │ 00:00:16.114 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/xwm.c:833] unhandled X11 property 380 (_NET_WM_ICON) for window 4194307
1470   │ [4248:4268:0829/063613.713701:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(590)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.StartServiceByName: object_path= /org/freedesktop/DBus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildSignaled: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications rec
       │ eived signal 11
1471   │ 00:00:16.255 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1472   │ 00:00:16.256 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/xwm.c:833] unhandled X11 property 299 (XdndAware) for window 4194307
1473   │ 00:00:16.256 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1474   │ 00:00:16.256 [DEBUG] [sway/tree/view.c:404] View 0x55b5903ea420 updated CSD to 0
1475   │ 00:00:16.308 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1476   │ 00:00:16.308 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1477   │ 00:00:16.309 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1478   │ 00:00:16.309 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/xwm.c:833] unhandled X11 property 381 (_NET_WM_OPAQUE_REGION) for window 4194307
1479   │ 00:00:16.311 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1480   │ 00:00:16.417 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1481   │ 00:00:16.417 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1482   │ 00:00:16.461 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1483   │ 00:00:16.461 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1484   │ 00:00:16.461 [DEBUG] [sway/desktop/xwayland.c:764] New xwayland unmanaged surface
1485   │ 00:00:16.461 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1486   │ 00:00:16.461 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/xwm.c:833] unhandled X11 property 387 (_NET_WM_USER_TIME) for window 4194307
1487   │ 00:00:16.462 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1488   │ 00:00:16.462 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1489   │ 00:00:16.462 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1490   │ 00:00:16.462 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1491   │ 00:00:16.520 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/xwm.c:833] unhandled X11 property 342 (CHROMIUM_TIMESTAMP) for window 4194308
1492   │ 00:00:16.520 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1493   │ 00:00:16.520 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/xwm.c:833] unhandled X11 property 276 (WM_STATE) for window 4194307
1494   │ 00:00:16.520 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1495   │ 00:00:16.520 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1496   │ 00:00:16.520 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1497   │ 00:00:16.520 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1498   │ 00:00:16.520 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1499   │ 00:00:16.520 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1500   │ 00:00:16.520 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1501   │ 00:00:16.520 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1502   │ 00:00:16.520 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1503   │ 00:00:16.520 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/xwm.c:833] unhandled X11 property 381 (_NET_WM_OPAQUE_REGION) for window 4194307
1504   │ 00:00:16.520 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/selection/selection.c:147] not handling selection events: no seat assigned to xwayland
1505   │ 00:00:16.520 [DEBUG] [wlr] [types/wlr_surface.c:748] New wlr_surface 0x55b5903e9f80 (res 0x55b5903efa10)
1506   │ 00:00:16.520 [DEBUG] [wlr] [xwayland/xwm.c:1674] New xwayland surface: 0x55b5903e9f80
1507   │ 00:00:16.520 [DEBUG] [sway/tree/view.c:404] View 0x55b5903ea420 updated CSD to 0
1508   │ 00:00:16.521 [DEBUG] [sway/tree/workspace.c:63] Adding workspace 4:   for output DP-1
1509   │ 00:00:16.521 [DEBUG] [sway/ipc-server.c:306] Sending workspace::init event
```